# RangeError: Error #1125: The index 0 is out of range 0

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, range, coordinates

Just been trying to randomise a bunch of button coordinates and managed this successfully using this code...

```
var coordinates:Vector.<Point> = new <Point>[
new Point(44, 420),
new Point(270, 420),
new Point(44, 550),
new Point(270, 550)
];


function positionAtRandomCoordinate(object:DisplayObject):void {
var index:int = Math.random() * coordinates.length;
var coordinate:Point = coordinates.splice(index, 1)[0];
object.x = coordinate.x;
object.y = coordinate.y;
}

positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons);
positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons_2);
positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons_3);
positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons_4);
```

This code works and when I start the game, the coordinates of the buttons randomise.

The problem I am having is I want these coordinates to randomise every time there is a correct answer.

My code for this is...

```
function checkAnswers() {
if (questionColour == answerColour){
    textLabeller(textBox);
    colourLabeller(textBox);
    updateScore();
positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons);
positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons_2);
positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons_3);
positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons_4);


    if (score > sharedData.data.highScore){
        sharedData.data.highScore = score;
        sharedData.flush();
        updateHiScore();


    }
    SecondsToCountDown = 6;

    }else {
    trace ("colours do not match");
    CountDownTimer.stop();
     gotoAndStop(3);
}

}
```

Most of the checkAnswers function is irrelevant to the question I think, it just shows how the function works by checking if two things match, something needs to happen.

When I run this, the buttons randomise like normal... but when I get a correct answer I get this error on my Output

RangeError: Error #1125: The index 0 is out of range 0.

...And they do not randomise anymore.

Any ideas SO? Would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Per Aarons suggestion, my revised code is...

```
function createCoordinatePositions():Vector.<Point> {
return new <Point>[
    new Point(44, 420),
    new Point(270, 420),
    new Point(44, 550),
    new Point(270, 550)
];
}

function positionAtRandomCoordinate(object:DisplayObject, coordinates:Vector.<Point>):void {
var index:int = Math.random() * coordinates.length;
var coordinate:Point = coordinates.splice(index, 1)[0];
object.x = coordinate.x;
object.y = coordinate.y;
}

function positionButtonsRandomly():void {
var coordinates:Vector.<Point> = createCoordinatePositions();
positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons, coordinates);
positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons_2, coordinates);
positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons_3, coordinates);
positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons_4, coordinates);
}
```

I then added to my checkAnswers() function...

```
positionButtonsRandomly();
```

It now works seamlessly with no Range Errors.

Thanks! All hail Aaron.

Comment: The 2nd time when that code is executed, your `coordinates` array is empty ! don't forget that you have used `coordinates.splice()` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-create your coordinates each time since you are removing all the points using `splice()` when you pick a random position.

For example, instead of using a top level `coordinates` var, you could create a function to create the possible coordinates:

```
function createCoordinatePositions():Vector.<Point> {
    return new <Point>[
        new Point(44, 420),
        new Point(270, 420),
        new Point(44, 550),
        new Point(270, 550)
    ];
}
```

Then modify your random position function to take an argument of possible coordinates:

```
function positionAtRandomCoordinate(object:DisplayObject, coordinates:Vector.<Pont>):void {
    // Same as before
}
```

Now to position all your buttons randomly you first create a new list of possible coordinates and pass it into each call to randomly position:

```
function positionButtonsRandomly():void {
    var coordinates:Vector.<Point> = createCoordinatePositions();
    positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons, coordinates);
    positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons_2, coordinates);
    positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons_3, coordinates);
    positionAtRandomCoordinate(answerButtons_4, coordinates);
    // By here the coordinates.length = 0
}
```

Comment: Hey Aaron, really appreciating the help you're giving on this project of mine. I have made these adjustments to the code and I seem to still be getting the range error whenever I get a correct answer. 

Any ideas?

Comment: It should work, post your updated code. It might help to put the entire thing in a function you can just call, like `positionButtonsRandomly()`. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Just saw your revision to your answer, now that it's in a function the checkAnswers can call on it properly and it all makes sense to me. Really big thanks for the help Aaron, you're a true genius.